# PHP monthly EMI calculation script

Tags: php

I want to create script for monthly EMI Calculation. Lets say my product value is Rs. 10000, interest rate = 12% and period is 3 months. How to calculate EMI value for this?. I tried with some formula? But not getting correct value. Can you tell me any idea for this? Thanks in advance

Work:

```
<?php 
$AMOUNT=10000; 
$intrest=12; // 12 percentage 
$plan=3; // 3 months 
$EMI=($AMOUNT * (($intrest/100)*($plan))); echo $EMI; 
?>
```

Comment: Are you asking the community to do the work for you? Can you post the code you've tried, followed by the data you used.

Comment: **1)** Why _php_? **2)** Why "sup dudes, do the code for me"? **3)** Why don't you go learn something and try do this for yourself? Damn...

Comment: <?php
$AMOUNT=10000;
$intrest=12; // 12 percentage
$plan=3; // 3 months

$EMI=($AMOUNT * (($intrest/100)*($plan)));
echo $EMI;
?>

Comment: @FranciscoCarvalho - Why complain about people asking for help on a help website?

Comment: @Steven - I don't believe anybody complains about people asking for help if they've made some effort themselves; but if they're simply asking others to do all the work for them.... OP claims to have tried some formulae, but not got the correct results; but they give no indication of what formulae they have already tried themselves, or even what the correct value should be for their input values - and this isn't even a problem with PHP code, it's an issue with basic mathematics

Comment: complete code http://www.nanhe.in/emi-calculator-code-in-php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When calculating amortization, it's important to match your rate to your term.  So if your loan compounds monthly, divide the rate by 12 to get the monthly interest rate.

[image: Amortization formula]

EMI = Amount * Rate * ( (1 + Rate) ^ Term / ( (1 + Rate) ^ Term - 1) )

```
$amount = 10000;
$rate = .12 / 12; // Monthly interest rate
$term = 3; // Term in months

$emi = $amount * $rate * (pow(1 + $rate, $term) / (pow(1 + $rate, $term) - 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made a github project long time ago. I added a datepicker where you can pick the starting date and duration. The scripts posts to itself and generate a table view of EMI for all the months. This should help you I guess.

You have to run the emicalculator.php in the php apache server.

https://github.com/deepakkoirala/EmiCalculator

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact value for total EMI and interest.

```
$princ =21500; //principal amount
$term = 9; //months
$intr =13/ 1200; //get percentage

$EMI= ceil($princ * $intr / (1 - (pow(1/(1 + $intr), $term)))); # This for total EMI

$TOT_INTEREST= ceil(($princ * $intr / (1 - (pow(1/(1 + $intr), $term))))*$term) - $princ; # This is for Total interest
```

Answer (score 0):

EMI calculation

```
function emi_of_cal($amount,$month,$percentage){
    $rateof = ($percentage/1200);
    $x = pow((1+$rateof),$month);
    
    $emi = (($amount*$rateof)*($x/($x-1)));
    $t_amnt = ($emi*$month);
    
    return [ "total" => $t_amnt, "emi" => $emi];
}
```

Example 2

```
<?php 
print_r(emi_of_cal(100000,36,7));
?>
```

Comment: Maybe if you want to keep this from getting deleted perhaps add in some verbiage or information about this answer, and most importantly; submit working code.

Comment: Thank you reported the issue resolved bro then check it

Answer (score -2):

```
=PMT(rate,nper,pv).
```

Let us check the EMI of Suraj by using the above formula.
It must be noted that the rate used in the formula should be the monthly rate, that is, 12%/12=1% or 0.01.
The number of periods represents the number of EMIs.

```
=PMT(0.12/12, 4*12, 445,000)= 11,718
```